# Does JavaScript maintain a reference to existing variables when objects are created using object literal syntax?

Tags: javascript, node.js, immutability, spread-syntax

This is a question about how JavaScript might add a reference to existing rather than creating new.

Here are some examples that are hopefully illustrative-enough, in the context of a Redux reducer because it is a familiar place for `spread operator` or `Object.assign()`:

> See here we are just returning an object literal with a string, so there is nothing that could drag in a reference **to** something that is existing elsewhere.

```
export default (state = {}, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case SOME_ACTION:
            return {
                props: 'something arbitray'
            }
    }
}
```

This one is the suspect problem:

> We are returning an object literal but we have included reference to `args[type]`. First, I need to know for certain, is this returning an object that **maintains** a link to whatever `args[type]` is currently set to? If `args[type]` were to get mutated after, would that be reflected in this returned object?

```
export default (state = {}, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case SOME_ACTION:
            return {
                props: args[type]
            }
    }
}
```

Here are two examples I suspect would not have this problem:

> Do I understand that correctly? Does JavaScript copy just the property and not maintain any reference to `args[type]`?

```
export default (state = {}, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case SOME_ACTION:
            return Object.assign({}, state, { props: args[type] })
    }
}
```

Here is another example that I recently learned might be syntactically identical to the `Object.assign()` syntax:

```
export default (state = {}, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case SOME_ACTION:
            return { ...state, props: args[type] }
    }
}
```

**The Questions:**

1. Does the spread operator do the exact same thing as `Object.assign()` in this context and create an entirely new object without risk of illegal-mutability due to maintaining a reference to `args[type]`? I need to be able to rely on the immutable state of the object after it is created.
2. Would the second example I showed maintain a live reference to `args[type]`?

I have some code that normally spreads in something, and I have a use case that omits that spread, so I am curious if that could be a problem. How can I guarantee random alterations of `args[type]` would not affect this returned object?

Would this be the correct answer?:

```
export default (state = {}, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case SOME_ACTION:
            return Object.assign({}, { props: args[type] })
    }
}
```

[**edit**]
I am able to reproduce the issue by doing this:

```js
const arr = ['one', 'two', 'three']

const args = {
  type: arr
}

const something = {
  props: args.type
}

arr.push('four') // Notice how this appears in something.props

console.log(something)
```

And this fixes it (so it seems to have something to do with primitives vs. maintaining an object reference):

```js
const arr = ['one', 'two', 'three']

const args = {
  type: arr[2]
}

const something = {
  props: args.type
}

arr[2] = 'what' // Notice how this doesn't appear in something.props

console.log(something)
```

> **Updated Question**

Is there a way to copy a `non-primitive` (ie: object/array) so that it breaks this reference?

I am noticing it doesn't work with `Object.assign()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`var a = 5;
var b = a;`

Does b maintains a reference to a ? No, it does not.
You are passing a value reference/value and not the parent object.

Comment: It's because a is a primitive. try `var a = [5]; var b = a; a.push(2); console.log(b);`

Comment: I want to know how I can ensure this behaviour does not occur.

Comment: In your example b still has no reference to a. they both point to the same object but not to each other. ie. if you assign something else to 'a'. and then do any operation on 'a'. That will not affect 'b'.

Comment: to understand you can imagine that [5] can exist (but only for a moment) even without any reference to it. Garbage collector will clean it up at next cycle but the thing to understand is that variable can hold primitive values and but only references objects. if you expect args[type] to be an object you can clone it using `Object.assign({}, args[type])`. Note object assign is doing shallow cloning.

Answer (score 0):

The answer seems to be that it's not an issue if the value is a primitive, because JavaScript does not store references to primitives.

The solution here is to spread in the object or array as a property:

```js
const arr = ['one', 'two', 'three']

const args = {
  type: arr
}

const something = {
  props: [...args.type]
}

arr.push('four') // notice how this isn't included

console.log(something)
```

This is helpful: [Is JavaScript a pass-by-reference or pass-by-value language?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/518000/is-javascript-a-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value-language)

Reading about shallow vs deep copying is also helpful, [Hard Copy vs Shallow copy javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40433889/hard-copy-vs-shallow-copy-javascript)

This solves the issue if the target is an object:

```js
const obj = {
  one: 'uno',
  two: 'dos',
  three: 'tres'
}

const args = {
  type: obj
}

const something = {
  props: Object.assign({}, args.type)
}

obj.four = 'four' // notice how this isn't included

console.log(something)
```

I recall this is described in a book by Eric Elliot also. `Object.assign()` is key for abandoning that reference. (and now in 2017, spread)

Comment: The real answer might be to not mutate the value, as suggested by the immutability tag on your question :-)

Comment: That is what we are doing, but I need to understand it enough to properly reason about it!

Comment: You should probably know the difference between reassignments and mutations too. Javascript never stores references but always values, even for object types. When you assign an object type to a variable, a copy of the  reference to this object is stored, not the reference itself. This subtle difference is important to understand Javascript's evaluation strategy.